# Assigning data to a dataset xarray does not work in script but works in console

Tags: python-xarray

I am using Spyder IDE and have a confusing problem in xarray. When data is assigned to a dataset in the script, the x and y axis are somehow transposed, but neither coordinates/dimensions are. However, when the data is assigned in the console, the data is done so correctly. Here is what I am doing:

```
# set up dataset
empty = np.zeros((19,(z_set.nzv).size,ny,nx))
vels = xr.Dataset(
       {
       "uvel": (["T","Z","Y","X"],empty),
       "vvel": (["T","Z","Y","X"],empty),
       },
       coords={
           "Y": (wvel["Y"]),
           "X": (wvel["X"]),
           "T": (wvel["T"].isel(T=days)),
       },)

# calculate some data
vels["uvel"][:,0,:,:] = -(g/f)*(eta["ETAN"].isel(T=days,Z=0)).differentiate("Y")
```

This figure shows the data calculated in the main script, and is incorrect.

[image: calculated in main script]

This figure shows the data calculated in the console, and is correct.

[image]

This is an example of the `eta` dataset used to calculate the data. Other datasets exist, like `wvel`. I have based setting up Dataset `vels` on the other Datasets.

```
In[32]: eta
Out[32]: 
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:      (T: 430, X: 200, Y: 200, Z: 1, Zmd000001: 1)
Coordinates:
  * X            (X) float64 5e+03 1.5e+04 2.5e+04 ... 1.985e+06 1.995e+06
  * Y            (Y) float64 5e+03 1.5e+04 2.5e+04 ... 1.985e+06 1.995e+06
  * T            (T) datetime64[ns] 2012-04-15 2012-04-16 ... 2013-06-18
Dimensions without coordinates: Z, Zmd000001
Data variables:
    diag_levels  (Zmd000001) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(1,), meta=np.ndarray>
    iter         (T) int32 dask.array<chunksize=(1,), meta=np.ndarray>
    ETAN         (T, Z, Y, X) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 1, 200, 200), meta=np.ndarray>
```

I am at a loss with this. I could transpose the data but that is a hack and not a fix.

Comment: Do you have a reproducible example?

Comment: I have put the script and data files in this google drive folder
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Cw_DR7RDHJX6DXtEkL7r_S0sd08HfSWn?usp=sharing

I've found a work around using numpy but it defeats the purpose of using xarray-dask

Comment: Can you reduce the example to the minimum required to reproduce the problem?

Comment: This should be more manageable https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1wZmBF_J3pgPLK5VwqioHVgKv5d0Dgway?usp=sharing

Comment: I mean something you can copy and paste into the question